# Scientific Notation for Quantities

Tags: output, units, notation

I am using Quantities (units) in Mathematica 11.3 and would like to express the numerical portion of the output in scientific notation. The command `ScientificForm[quantity]` does not work.

Comment: Example code please.

Comment: Typically the output _is_ scientific notation - for instance `Quantity[0.000000000000009, "Joules"]` has the output `Quantity[9.\[CenterDot]10^-15, "Joules"]`. If you're using something like `Quantity[9/Pi*-1000000, "Joules"]`, you may need to do `N@Quantity[9/Pi*-1000000, "Joules"]`, which results in the output `Quantity[-2.86479\[CenterDot]10^6, "Joules"]`.

Comment: Does `ScientificForm[N @ quantity]` do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

When the argument to `Quantity` is in arbitrary precision (e.g. an exact integer), it does not get converted automatically to scientific notation. You can force the conversion if you numericize the input, converting it e.g. to machine precision:

```
Quantity[2000000, "Kilograms"]
N @ Quantity[2000000, "Kilograms"]
```

[image: exact output]

[image: numerical output in scientific notation]

Note that, however, even machine precision numbers whose exponents are "small" according to some preset threshold do *not* get converted to scientific notation.

```
Quantity[2000., "Kilograms"]
```

[image: 2000 does not get converted]

I have not (yet) found a way to force that conversion at will.

Comment: Looking at some DVs (``QuantityUnits`Private`makeNumberValue``) it looks like the `10^6` cutoff is hardcoded...

Comment: @b3m2a1 Interesting, thank you for digging it up. It's unfortunate that the cutoff is hardcoded.

Comment: On the other hand this *should* work (it does for me): ``Quantity[ScientificForm[10.^5], "USDollars"]``

Comment: @b3m2a1 ... as does, interestingly, `ScientificForm[N@Quantity[1000, "Kilograms"]]` which, I see now, was suggested by [Carl Woll in comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192533/scientific-notation-for-quantities/192552?noredirect=1#comment501255_192533).